# Understanding a statement: Uniform convergence of functions

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to understand the following statement:

> Let $f$ be a real function defined on an interval $I$ and let $\{f_n\}$ a sequence of functions that converges uniformly to $f$ on $I$. For each $k \in \Bbb N$, there is a subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}$ such that $|f_{n_k}(x)-f(x)|<2^{-k}$ for all $x \in I$.

I can't understand it because they say that for every fixed $k \in \Bbb N$, there is a subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}$, and here the subsequence's index is $k$, so I think it doesn't make sense, shouldn't they use an index other than $k$? Maybe I'm misinterpreting the statement, but I'm not sure.

Could someone please explain this to me?

Thank you so much in advace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, the way it is written is simply wrong. What they are saying is that we can find a subsequence $\langle f_{n_k}\rangle$ such that $|f_{n_k}-f|<2^{-k}$ over $I$.

*Proof* Since $f_n\to f$ uniformly on $I$, for each $\varepsilon >0$ there exists $n_\varepsilon$ such that $n\geqslant n_\varepsilon$ implies $$|f_n(t)-f(t)|<\varepsilon$$ over $I$. Now choose $\varepsilon =2^{-k}$. Then you get for each $k=1,2,3,\ldots$ an integer $n_k$ such that...? You have to take care in making $n_1<n_2<n_3<\cdots$, but that is not hard: if $n_1$ has been chosen and you get a $n_2'$, let $n_2=\max\{n_1,n_2' \}+1$. Continue in this fashion.

Comment: So, would it be more correct to say that there is a subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}$ such that $|f_{n_k}(x)-f(x)|<2^{-k}$ for all $x \in I$ and for all $k \in \Bbb N$? Because the way they say it makes me think that for each $k \in \Bbb N$ there is a subsequence...

Comment: Yes, as the statement was written, it made no sense. This makes sense. :)

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm still having a blast with rotations and reflections.

Comment: Ok, thank you @PedroTamaroff and TedShifrin :)